# Laravel 7 - server only serving root page

Tags: php, laravel, apache, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to serve a Laravel 7 site on my server, built using a Raspberry Pi and storing the files on an external hard drive.

I cloned my Laravel project from Github, ran `composer install` and after a bit of fiddling and configuration, the root page loaded. However, the root page is the *only* route that will load. Neither my own routes nor the auth routes generated by Laravel work. Any attempt to access a different route leads to a 404 error thrown by Apache on my server.

Here is my VirtualHost config file in Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myurl.tld

    ServerAdmin  myemail@example.com
    DocumentRoot /mnt/external/public_html/MyProject/public

    <Directory /mnt/external/public_html/MyProject>
         AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Not sure what is going on here. The same thing happens with projects generated on the server as well as the cloned project.

Permissions on `/mnt/external/public_html/MyProject` are set to 775 all the way up to `external`, and the whole path is owned by the `www-data` user.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below VirtualHost config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myurl.tld

    ServerAdmin  myemail@example.com
    DocumentRoot /mnt/external/public_html/MyProject/public

    <Directory /mnt/external/public_html/MyProject/public>            
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart Apache.